# How are objects laid out in memory in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management

While reading about inheritance and categories, i found that memory concepts are slightly different that what i learned in C++.

Can anyone throw some light on a basic issue as to how objects are laid out in memory in objective c.

What is the message mechanism working in background when i use any object in Xcode.

Comment: That sounds like at least two rather broad questions. Maybe going into more detail?

Comment: if the first question is answered, the second will follow :)

Comment: Do you mean the extrinsic layout of objects -- that is, how all objects are arranged in respect to one another -- or the intrinsic layout -- that is, the arrangement of the contents of individual objects? Both answers are pretty boring, but I figured I'd ask which one you want. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can see the layout of an ObjC object in the objc.h header file on your system:

```
/// Represents an instance of a class.
struct objc_object {
    Class isa;         /**< Pointer to the class definition of which this 
                        *   object is an instance. */
};
```

You can find an article showing how objc_msgSend works (by building a much more primitive version of it) here:

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-11-16-lets-build-objc_msgsend.html

Comment: these two articles are very tedious. can someone give me a concise answer??

Comment: methods are stored on the Class object and looked up at runtime. There's your concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this hope it will help you.

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-12-17-custom-object-allocators-in-objective-c.html

Comment: Please try to provide some commentary as to why this link is useful and what information it contains.